# React hook form - how to set error with multiple types for a single field and clear each type separately?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I would like to set multiple errors for a single field and then clear each type of an error separately.
This is how I am setting up error now:

```
        const incomes = getValues("incomes");
        const dateGaps = findDateGaps(incomes, startDate);
        const overlappingPeriods = getOverlappingPeriods(incomes);

        if (dateGaps?.length) {
            const message = `Missing incomes for ${dateGaps.length > 1 ? "periods" : "period"}: ${dateGaps.map(
                (gap) => ` ${gap.from} - ${gap.to}`
            )}`;
            setError("incomes", { type: "periodGaps", message });
        }

        if (overlappingPeriods?.length) {
            setError("incomes", {
                type: "overlappingPeriods",
                message: JSON.stringify(overlappingPeriods),
            });
        }

        if (!dateGaps?.length) {
            clearErrors("incomes");
        }

        if (!overlappingPerioder?.length) {
            clearErrors("incomes");
        }
```

With this setup I am clearing all errors for "incomes" field. How can I delete only a single type?

Comment: For example, `clearErrors("incomes", "overlappingPeriods");`

Comment: ```clearErrors``` expects only 0-1 argument @KArslan